# How to create HTML5 WebRTC peer connections with datachannels multiple peers?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I can create a peer connection and establish connection between two users, but I totally confused on working with multiple peers.

How do I work multiple peers using a [WebRTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC) datachannel?

Comment: "How to work multiple peers using webrtc datachannel?" [Read a tutorial?](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&gs_rn=12&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=hHVSr2tSW4U3e_blx_c87w&cp=15&gs_id=v&xhr=t&q=webrtc+tutorial&es_nrs=true&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=webrtc+tutorial&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46340616,d.ZWU&fp=950695db4654083c&biw=1366&bih=677&ion=1)

Comment: thanks @Bojangles. none of the articles explained about datachannel and multiple peers! can you just give me a demo link?

Comment: Here is a sample with a multi-video-chat using WebRTC http://xsockets.net/academy/xva-05-01-webrtc-basics and there are also some datachannel examples in there.

Comment: You did a good question, and the answer is hard to find. It's a shame some mod close it, denying the community an expert opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. I think you need to connect to all peers separately or use one that acts as a server.